# l'Hôpital guidelines

Tags: calculus, limits

Suppose we want to evaluate

$$\lim_{x \to 0} \; x \log (x)$$

If we write this in the form $x/(1/\log(x))$, then l'Hôpital's rule does not work, but if we write it as $\log(x)/(1/x)$, it does. Is there any sort of general guideline to choosing the numerator and denominator?

Comment: Note that the limit as written does not exist, and L'Hopital's is irrelevant: $\log x$ is not defined on an interval containing $0$: it's only defined to the right of $0$. Of course, you can take the limit as $x\to 0^+$. Rule of thumb: make choices that make the derivatives *simpler* or at least *no harder* than the original. $\frac{1}{\log x}$ has a derivative which is harder than the original, so it's not a good choice.

Answer (score 7):

There is no known general *algorithm* to choose which way to apply L'Hospital's rule. Sometimes $\rm\: N'/D'\:$ works and sometimes $\rm\: (D^{-1})'/(N^{-1})'\:$ works. If you iteratively try both cases then you get combinatorial explosion: $\rm\:2^k\:$ possibilities upon $\rm\:k\:$ successive applications of the rule (not to mention possibly intractable intermediate expression swell with expressions that grow under differentiation, e.g. exponentials). There are some *heuristics* that *sometimes* help in practice, e.g. see  the papers below on early *heuristic* approaches to computing limits in computer algebra systems.

D. Gruntz. [On Computing Limits in a Symbolic Manipulation System.](http://e-collection.library.ethz.ch/eserv/eth:40284/eth-40284-02.pdf)
Steven J. Harrington. [A symbolic limit evaluation program in REDUCE.](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=1088286)
Jean-Pierre Laurent. [A program that computes limits using heuristics to evaluate the indeterminate forms.](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/0004-3702(73)90001-5)

However, there *are* effective *algorithms* for computing limits of large classes of elementary and special functions. They do *not* employ L'Hopital's rule. In fact I devised the first known algorithm when I was an MIT student. It employs  a sort of generalized power series expansion in terms of certain asymptotic kernels (technically 
it employs differential valuation theory in Hardy-Rosenlicht fields). For an introduction to similar ideas see G. Edgar's [Transseries for beginners.](http://arxiv.org/abs/0801.4877)

Below is an example of my (Macsyma) algorithm 
computing (my generalization of) a limit suggested by Rich Schroeppel, who - not believing 
in the existence of an algorithm for limits - designed a 
monstrous expression in an attempt to thwart the algorithm
[image]

Comment: Maple can do this one too:

> d1:= exp(exp(exp(exp(-exp(exp(x))-exp(x)-x+a)+x)))-exp(exp(exp(x)));


>  limit(d1, x=infinity);

$$e^a$$

Comment: @Rob Back in the dark ages - when I first devised my algorithm (circa 1980) - no computer algebra system could handle such limits. Then it was a major open problem in computer algebra to find a general algorithm for computing limits - to complement the recently discovered algorithms for integration and ODE solution. Now most leading systems have (partially) implemented some variation on these ideas (my work, or Shackell's, or transseries - which are all closely related).

Answer (score 5):

One general guideline is, you want to write your indeterminate form as $f/g$ where $f'/g'$ is going to be "simpler" than $f/g$.  Now taking the derivative of a logarithm  makes it simpler (i.e. rational rather than transcendental), so a logarithmic factor should, if possible, be isolated by itself as $f$ or $g$.  The same goes for arctan.